# Using Ajax for datatable

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I am using datatable now and I am unable to receive the data from my ajax file to datatable codes.

My codes are as follows:

AJAX

```
<?php
function functionClass($id) {
        // create sql query
     $Class = "SELECT class.id, class.day, class.start_time, class.end_time, subject.subject_name, tutor.tutor_id, tutor.tutor_name AS t_name, classroom.room
     FROM class, subject, tutor, classroom
     WHERE class.subject_id = subject.id
     AND class.tutor_id = tutor.id
     AND class.classroom_id = classroom.id";

     //$resultClass = mysqli_query($link, $viewClass) or die(mysqli_error($link));

}
?>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
`$(document).ready( {`
    $.fn.dataTable.TableTools.defaults.aButtons = [ "csv" ];
    $('.datatable').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        serverSide: true,
        processing: true,       
        lengthMenu: [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ],
        ajax: {
            url: "http://localhost/FYP/dt/class/",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                method: "get"     
                }
            }, 
            columns : [
                {
                    data: "id",
                    render: function(data, type, row) {
                        return <?php echo $row['id'] ?> + row.id + '/">' + data + '</a>';                    
                    }
]
```

My datatable method is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
        <a href="addNewClass.php" class="btn btn-success"><span class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></span> New Class</a>    
    </div>        
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped datatable" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr> 
                <th class="all">S/N</th>
                <th class="min-tablet-l">Day</th>
                <th class="min-tablet-l">Start Time</th>
                <th class="min-tablet-l">End Time</th>
                <th class="min-tablet-l">Subject</th>
                <th class="min-tablet-l">Staff ID</th>                
                <th class="min-tablet-l">Tutor</th>
                <th class="min-tablet-l">Classroom</t                  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tbody>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tbody>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr> 
                <th>S/N</th>
                <th>Day</th>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>End Time</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Staff ID</th>                
                <th>Tutor</th>
                <th>Classroom</th>                
            </tr>
        </tfoot>            
    </table>
</div>
```

UPDATE: I have resolved most issue now when I am initialising the table I get this error "3. Warning: Cannot reinitialise Data" A look into my console it tells me POST http://localhost/FYP/dt/functionClass/ 404 (Not Found)

Comment: can you please post the DataTable Method?

Comment: I have added in the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace and try with this..

```
ajax: {
       url: "http://localhost/FYP/dt/class/",
       type: "POST",
       data: {  method: "get"  } //data to be sent
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

first you should check the ajax syntax .you a an error:add `,` after url.

```
url: "http://localhost/FYP/dt/class/",
        type: "POST",
```